# Object not deserialising correctly on put request with web api

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I am using web-api 2 and postman rest client to test.

I have a method definition which looks like this:

```
[Route("api/bob/user")]
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateUser(User user)
```

The user object looks like this:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}

public interface IUser
{
    string Firstname { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

In postman i've set a put request and set the content type to JSON(application/json) I have specified the following in the body as raw:

```
{
   "user": {"Firstname":"Bob","Lastname":"Smith"}
}
```

When I send the request the object type is detected but none of the properties are populated (they are all null), leading me to believe the de-serialisation is failing.

If I change the method signature to object I get the json string and can deserialise it to a user object. I'd much prefer strong typing if possible.

my webapiconfig looks like this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

I also add a screenshot of the test client:

[image: content type shown]

Comment: Are you using `Content-Type: application/json` in your request?

Comment: Also try adding "[FromBody]" attribute before "User user"

Comment: yes I am postman has this set I have added a screen shot to show this.

Comment: no FromBody makes no difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not put the `user` property before. Your JSON should look like:

```
{
   "Firstname": "Bob",
   "Lastname": "Smith"
}
```

In order for the model binder to bind to the model.

If you wish to go with your current JSON, your `User` model should look like

```
public class User {
   public User User { get; set; }  
}
```

Also make sure you use `application/json` as the content type.

Comment: *facepalm*, you are correct, will accept this as soon as SO lets me. For those who don't understand the answer, the object in the json is not of type user so the serialisation fails..